# Adjust image of rect

Tags: python, pygame

I want to move the image of a Rect object, is this possible?

examples:
1 - make a waterfall with the water animated (make the water image scroll)
2 - adjust location of the image not the rect

note: these are just examples not the code I am working on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shift the surface image in place with [`pygame.Surface.scroll`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.scroll). For instance, call

```py
water_surf.scroll(0, 1)
```

However, this will not satisfy you. See [`pygame.Surface.scroll`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.scroll):

> Move the image by dx pixels right and dy pixels down. dx and dy may be negative for left and up scrolls respectively. **Areas of the surface that are not overwritten retain their original pixel values**.

You may want to write a function that overwrites the areas wich are not overwritten, with the pixel that is scrolled out of the surface:

```py
def scroll_y(surf, dy):
    scroll_surf = surf.copy()
    scroll_surf.scroll(0, dy)
    if dy > 0:
        scroll_surf.blit(surf, (0, dy-surf.get_height()))
    else:
        scroll_surf.blit(surf, (0, surf.get_height()+dy))
    return scroll_surf
```

once per frame to create a water flow effect like a waterfall.

To center an image in a rectangular area, you need to get the bounding rectangle of the image and set the center of the rectnagle through the center of the area. Use the rectangle to `blit` the image:

```py
area_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, w, h)
image_rect = surf.get_rect()
image_rect.center = area_rect.center
screen.blit(surf, image_rect)
```

The same in one line:

```py
screen.blit(surf, surf.get_rect(center = area_rect.center))
```

---

Minimal example:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-SCroll](https://replit.com/@Rabbid76/PyGame-Scroll#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

def scroll_y(surf, dy):
    scroll_surf = surf.copy()
    scroll_surf.scroll(0, dy)
    if dy > 0:
        scroll_surf.blit(surf, (0, dy-surf.get_height()))
    else:
        scroll_surf.blit(surf, (0, surf.get_height()+dy))
    return scroll_surf

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 400))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rain_surf = pygame.image.load('rain.png')
dy = 0

run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False          

    window_center = window.get_rect().center
    scroll_surf = scroll_y(rain_surf, dy)
    dy = (dy + 1) % rain_surf.get_height()

    window.fill(0)
    window.blit(scroll_surf, scroll_surf.get_rect(center = window_center))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: The works brilliantly!  however how would i be able to strait away canter an image on a rect?

Comment: @MottledKarma517 The comment section is not intended to ask follow up questions. Anyway, I've extended the answere.